# Can't connect to IMAP with PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

i'm trying to connect php with an imap server but i'm getting this error:

> Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream
>   {mail.XXX.it:143/imap/notls/norsh}INBOX Array ( [0] => SECURITY
>   PROBLEM: insecure server advertised AUTH=PLAIN [1] => Can not
>   authenticate to IMAP server: AUTHENTICATE mechanism not supported,
>   mate ) Cannot connect: 1
>
> When trying to connect mail.XXX.it:143/imap/notls/norsh

And this error:

> Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream
>   {mail.XXX.it:143/imap/secure/notls/norsh}INBOX Array ( [0] => Can't do
>   secure authentication with this server ) Cannot connect: 1
>
> When trying to connect mail.XXX.it:143/imap/secure/notls/norsh

How can i get around this?
(Hosting has no SSL security)
Thanks

Comment: It would help if you add the line where you use  imap_open().. wrong user/pass ?

Comment: Tried alternate ports?

Comment: You should add details of the IMAP server with which you are trying to communicate to your question

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking your ssl certs? If the server has a self-signed cert it might cause
php's imap library to throw a configurable error (possibly what you are getting). Furthermore the imap library is installed as a package, sometime separately, you might want to check your configurations for this lib.

Tell me what you think and a curl -v basic auth attempt readout might be helpful,
Cheers